# How can I have comments in author.php like in single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is their any plugin or a workaround that will allow a registered user to comment into author.php ? Just like there is the comments template into single.php but I want that in author.php

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a plugin out there, though, never have researched about this.

However, you might get around this by creating a page for each author, maybe?

Comment: You mean to have their author.php but also a page associated? As far as I know you have to do that manually for each author, so not the best solution of a self registered blog.
What about having a php form that will use the id of author, commenter name, comment date etc, save it into db and when you visit the author with id 1 it will show the last comments ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such a plugin, you might consider to ask at [wordpress answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) as well or searching through the [plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/).

Comments in wordpress need a post they are assigned to. Authors aren't a post, so a workaround could be to create a post for each user or a custom post type with comments and assign one per user. Then integrate the comments template in `author.php` by referencing that post of the post-type by the user.

Comment: What about having a php form that will use the id of author, commenter name, comment date etc, save it into db and when you visit the author with id 1 it will show the last comments ?

Comment: Then you would re-invent the wheel. Sounds possible but too much work to me.

Comment: If it's the only solution I guess I have too search it.

Comment: You can try the worpdress answers stackoverflow site as well. That are some more wordpress cracks.